# Issue in VueJs - isCustomElement

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-component

I am having a strange issue in the VueJS project, as when I am adding and trying to use the component from npm.

It shows a warning in the browser console and shows nothing in the output.

For example, I have tried to use a calendar control
https://edisdev.github.io/vue-datepicker-ui/examples.html

I have installed it and added the same in the components section but still, it shows [image]

I have also tried to add

```
app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = (tag) => tag.includes('-')
```

in **main.ts** but it has not worked.

Comment: Please post your Vue component code

Comment: It's an installed component buddy... I have given the link in the post.

Comment: You're trying to use the npm component within your own component, aren't you? Your errors indicate that the component hasn't been registered in your component properly, but I can't tell because I don't see your component code.